Dealing with extremely strict OpenAPI/Swagger interpreter's vague error messages
I have an API that a client is trying to use and they need Swagger documentation for it. They take it and upload it into a very strict interpreter that gives unhelpful error messages and I'm not sure what the problem with my docs are. Here's an abbreviated part that is the problem area:
{
  "info": { ... },
  "paths": { ... },
  "components" : {
    "schemas" : {
      "ItemImport" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "items" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/ItemImportResource"
            },
            "example" : [ {
              "date_field" : "2020-01-01"
            } ]
          }
        }
      },
      "ItemImportResource" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "required" : ["date_field"],
        "properties" : {
          "date_field" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "format" : "date",
            "pattern": "^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$",
            "description" : "description",
            "example" : "2020-01-01",
            "minLength": 0,
            "maxLength": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

This is the error that comes back
Swagger document is invalid -  Data and type mismatch found. #/components/schemas/ItemImport/properties/items/example/0/date_field

It obviously doesn't like the date_field but according to the Swagger docs https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/ I don't know what other fields to add.
Furthermore if I change "pattern" from
"pattern": "^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$",

to
"pattern": /^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/,

I then get this error
Swagger document is invalid - The field 'info' in 'document' object is REQUIRED. #/info The field 'paths' in 'document' object is REQUIRED. #/paths

which also makes no sense because I have both the info and paths keys in the docs (I just omitted the innards of them).
Anyone have any idea what I'm missing here?

Seems like this may be an error on the editor they are using.. Do you know which one it is?  Your example checks out on multiple doc generators I tested.  editor.swagger.io  editor-next.swagger.io  redocly.github.io/redoc

That's probably what I'm going to ascertain next. It's part of a larger proprietary software suite they have. It's also something that had to have changed recently because the docs used to work for them and them getting flagged is a very recent thing.

it could be something like they updated their Ajv validator instance to use strict mode which is set by default and it doesn't like some patterns used in some schemas. That makes it non-compliant with JSON Schema spec out of the box.  to make it compliant, you have to set strict: false.

Is that set in the interpreter engine or something I pass in somewhere in my docs?
